# How to integrate TOSCA with github

Tags: automation, build-automation, tosca

I have just started using TOSCA. Currenly using version 11.2.

1. I would like to ask can we integrate TOSCA with github to store the repository?
2. if yes, then how can we do it?
3. which version to use for this ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the latest version available and then connect to GitHub as described here: https://support.tricentis.com/community/manuals_detail.do?lang=en&url=tosca_commander/github.htm

Comment: Thanks Rolko, I will look into this reference link shared